# Firefox 100% Width Overextending Parent Div

Tags: html, css, firefox, width

I have two textboxes, and a single 1 px div contained in a div. The parent div has auto height, with 100% width.

After all this there is another div which is 100% width and height, this div is displayed correctly in Webkit, but it overextends the border of the parent div by about 2-3 px.

Here is all relevant code, I have narrowed it down to JUST these, and I have checked the parent divs width and height in Firefox by colouring the background red, and it doesn't extend (the red) when I do that.

I do seem to remember reading something about having to tell Firefox, or Webkit etc... how to define width, but I cannot remember the CSS for that and I have spent about 45 minutes Googling everything I can to try and find it again.

**HTML**

```
 <!-- CREDENTIALS -->
            <div class="centreLoginForm-Credentials">

                <div id="disabledDiv"></div>

                <input id="usernameCred" class="textInput top" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <!--<div class="dividerDiv textBoxGrey"></div>-->
                <input id="passwordCred" class="textInput bottom" type="password" placeholder="Password">

            </div>
            <!-- CREDENTIALS END -->
```

**CSS**

```
.centreLoginForm-Credentials
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    position: relative;

    margin-top: 10px;

    display: table;

    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);

    border-radius: 3px; 
    border: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
}

#disabledDiv
{
    position: absolute;

    /*z-index: -10;*/

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);  
}
```

Comment: Just tried something very quickly: **I removed **display: table**,** wasn't sure why that was still there and it fixed the problem. I am confused as to why it fixed it though, can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 7):

The 100% width does not include padding and/or borders. If you want to include these try this css:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, as Willem said, padding and borders are added.

And as you said, `display: table` is a strange choice for this div.

But setting `display: block` alone isn't enough, you should remove horizontal borders too:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ks4Ur/

```
display: block;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
```

Edit: and +1 for the AsciiArt nick that made me laugh :)